# Does WCF support SNI (Server Name Indication)

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, sni

I would like to consume a 3rd party WCF service using basic authentication, but I also need to use SNI. I've hacked together the following example (minus real endpoint stuff) to show what I've setup and the error I get.

Any help much appreciated as I know little about WCF and nothing about SNI.

### Config

```
<endpoint 
 address="https://their.server.com/theirservice.svc"
 binding="basicHttpBinding"  
  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISyncFramework2"
  contract="ISyncFramework" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISyncFramework2">
 </endpoint>

       <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISyncFramework2" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
       allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
               maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
           <security mode="Transport">
             <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
                 realm="" />
           </security>
         </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>
```

### code:

```
            var service = new SyncFrameworkClient();
            service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
            service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "thepassword";

            service.method() // fails!
```

the call to *method* fails with:

The requested service, 'https://their.server.com/theirservice.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.

### The server trace

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is usually a service-side issue not a client-side problem. SNI is a server technology to improve SSL handshaking and in the Microsoft stack is [only supported in the unreleased IIS 8](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1096/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability/) version. Unless the third-party rolled their own SNI/SSL stack it seems unlikely that their WCF service would require it.

On the actual exception you're getting, it seems that something along the lines of [this blog post](http://daveonsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/12/wcf-iis-require-secure-channel.html) would likely be the cause of the problem. Your config and code snippets look right for basicHttpBinding using SSL and basic HTTP authentication.